# Error 1033 When Sourcing Python Script from R

Tags: python, r, error-handling, reticulate

I have a python script that sends a message to Discord.
From R, I have executed the following succesfuly several times:

```r
library(reticulate)
use_python('C:/Users/OfirL1/Miniconda3/', required = T)
source_python('C:/Users/OfirL1/Google Drive (ronnydorone@mail.tau.ac.il)/Model Data/message.py')
# use sourced function here
```

But today, without any changes, I now get:

```r
## Error in python_config(python_version, required_module, python_version,  : 
##   Error 1033 occurred running C:/Users/OfirL1/Miniconda3/python.exe  
## In addition: Warning message:
## In system2(command = python, args = paste0("\"", config_script,  :
##   running command '"C:/Users/OfirL1/Miniconda3/python.exe" "D:/OfirL1/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/reticulate/config/config.py"' had status 1033
```

I don't understand why, or what 1033 stands for (have not been able to find any information on it).

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that your path you give `use_python` is incorrect, you should specify the entire path to where python is located for example:

```
use_python('C:\\Users\\davidsr\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32', required = T)
```

This will not raise errors, and in case you wonder how to find the full path **->** you can run the following simple `python` code below and it will output you the path needed:

```
import os
import sys
print(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I do have the full path to the Python executable in my code, just when writing it here I decided to skip it. But do you mean that the path is supposed to be to the directory, not the executable?

Comment: Exactly, this was your problem; next time specify it so it will be clearer

Comment: I updated the question with my full paths. This does not solve the error however.

Comment: @RonnyEfronny is it a virtual environment or the standard python? it seems that there authorization issues

Comment: Standard python as installed by Miniconda3.

Comment: @RonnyEfronny I would try download `python` from the site and retry, there might be some issue with the `python` under the miniconda installation

Comment: I use this particular one in pure Python work with PyCharm as well and there are no issues at all, this sounds odd.

Comment: I agree that its odd, but that might be the issue; worthwhile to check it; Did the `R` code with `python` calling worked before? If yes when did you changed something?

Comment: It did, and I changed nothing about it before it ceased working this morning.

Comment: @RonnyEfronny So it is peculiar, it has to do with something that is not related to the code itself